# dbus service does not register to the dbus

Tags: python, linux, ipc, dbus

I created a service using dbus-python which outputs the time. The problem is that the dbus service is not registering to the dbus services and when I call the service I get the error

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.gkbrk.Time was not provided by any .service files
```

This is the code:
Service.py

```
import dbus
import dbus.service
import time


class Time(dbus.service.Object):

    
    def __init__(self):
        self.bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        name = dbus.service.BusName('com.gkbrk.Time', bus=self.bus)
        super().__init__(name, '/Time')
    @dbus.service.method('com.gkbrk.Time', out_signature='s')
    def CurrentTime(self):
        """Use strftime to return a formatted timestamp
        that looks like 23-02-2018 06:57:04."""
        
        formatter = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
        return time.strftime(formatter)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import dbus.mainloop.glib
    from gi.repository import GLib
    
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    object = Time()
    loop.run()
```

Client.py

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SessionBus()

time = bus.get_object('com.gkbrk.Time', '/Time')

curr = time.CurrentTime()
print('The current time is', curr)
```

How to solve this? I run the service.py and nothing happens, if I list the dbus services, my service does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine, you may need to adjust the security policy of session bus under `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf` or `/etc/dbus-1/session.d` to allow owning a name on the bus.